# Error too many login attempts: Sending email campaign using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

In my application I have a few email campaigns that get sent out roughly about once a month.  Two of my email campaigns have a mailing list that consist of roughly 50+ recipients, whereas the other one can have as many as 800+.  I ran into this issue recently where I was trying to send the large email campaign and towards the end when I got this error: `Error: too many login attempts.  Please try again later.`.  After doing some research it looks like it would be best if I used the pooling parameter in nodemailer's options when creating a transport.

I've looked on their site regarding this matter but it's a very vague section and doesn't really show how it can be used in an application.  Is it as simple as just adding `pool: true` to my transport options? Or is their more to it than that.  I'm using gmail's smtp and I know that they rate limit the amount of emails that can be sent out at once so having a pool to do them in parallel might cause issues.

Here is what my email campaign file looks like:

```
.
.
.
import { FormatEmailReport } from '../imports/Utilities/EmailReports';
import { smtpTransport } from '../imports/Utilities/EmailService';
import performance from 'perf_hooks';

export const SendCampaign = () => {
    try {
        let date = new Date();
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 4);   // get 4 months prior to today
        date= ConvertDateToYMD(date);

   
        getEmailList(date).then(email_list => {
             FormatEmailsToSend(email_list);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log('ERROR: micro.getEmailList: ' + e);
        }) 
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR: micro.SendCampaign: ' + e);
    }
}

export const FormatEmailsToSend = async (email_list) => {
    try {

        let accepted = [];
        let rejected = [];
        let t0 = performance.performance.now();
          for(let pbid in email_list){  
            let customer = email_list[pbid][0];
            let to = customer.Email;
            let txt = `
                <div width="100%">
                    <p>Hi ${customer.Name},</p>
                    <p>this is a courtesy email from the server</p>
                </div>
            `

            let result = await SendEmail("myemail.com", to, "myemail.com", `Email Subject`, txt, attachment, customer.CustomerID, customer.PBID);
            result.Status == 'accepted' ? accepted.push(result) : rejected.push(result);
        } 

        let t1 = performance.performance.now();
        let execution_time = (t1-t0)/1000;
        FormatEmailReport(accepted,rejected,execution_time,`Email Report`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR: micro.FormatEmailsToSend: ' + e);
    }
}

export const SendEmail = (from, to, bcc, subject, msg, attachments, customer_id, pbid) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
                from: from, // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
                to: to, 
                bcc: bcc,
                subject: subject, // subject
                html: msg, // body
                attachments: attachments
            }, function (error, res) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(`Email FAILED for address: ${to}! ERROR: ${error}`);
                    reject({CustomerID: customer_id, PBID: pbid, Email: to, Status: 'rejected', Msg: error})
                } else {
                    resolve({CustomerID: customer_id, PBID: pbid, Email: to, Status: 'accepted', Msg: res.response})
                }
        
                smtpTransport.close();
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR: micro.SendEmail: ' + e);
            reject({CustomerID: customer_id, PBID: pbid, Email: to, Status: 'rejected', Msg: e})
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my EmailService file:

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import env from '../../../env.config.json';

const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: env.SalesEmail.SERVICE,  // "Gmail"
    auth: {
        user: env.SalesEmail.AUTH.USER,
        pass: env.SalesEmail.AUTH.PASS
    }
});

module.exports = {smtpTransport}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I might be able to use nodemailer's pool instead of a single connection that would be great. TIA!

Comment: Although your code seems to be missing a critical line in FormatEmailsToSend, which I assume is a for loop, it looks like you are trying to simultaneously send all emails. No sane mail server will allow 800 parallel connections from a single user. Try some batching.

Comment: @idmean which critical line is missing?  Also I'm using promises so the for loop is asynchronous, so it's only sending one after the other and not all at once.

Comment: @idmean I've updated my question.  I missed the for loop when typing this up.